# How do I preview a template?

Tags: wikipedia

I wish to edit a template that is frequently used. How do I preview it so I don't have to publish in order to view the results?

Answer (score 1):

*From [Wikipedia:Template_sandbox_and_test_cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_sandbox_and_test_cases)*

**You should use a sandbox for testing templates:**

> [Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Template) are a very powerful feature of the [MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) software used for [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia), but mistakes can be easily made, even by experienced users. Complex templates should therefore be accompanied by [sandboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) and [test cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case) to prevent bugs. Temporary sandboxes [X1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:X1)-[X20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:X20) or the [Template Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Template_sandbox) may be useful places to try new experiments or for users new to template development.

Have a look at [How to create /sandbox and /testcases subpages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_sandbox_and_test_cases#How_to_create_/sandbox_and_/testcases_subpages) (or the next subtitle for updating existing `/sandbox` and `/testcases`) - I'm intentionally not copying and quoting the method described to here, since it can cause more un-updated content.

**It would be better to stick to the [main article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_sandbox_and_test_cases) on that topic and check the current working method for the time of creating/updating templates.**